"00000000000000"
Who am I definitely refering to? Explain.

         SENROSNANOGENVENIMOHYEANSANRAIGCAIGGORGIMOHYCRIGEORENIVNCOERRYIMOHY


The name's...

 Bond, James Bond...

First of all, the title - 14 zeros, or...

 seven double-zeros, hinting at double-oh seven (007), Bond's code number.

Next, the string - this is:

 ...a mixed list of first and last names of seven actors to have played James Bond in movies, with a particular letter omitted from their names each time, like so:

 SE(A)N (B)ROSNAN (R)OGE(R) N(I)VEN (T)IMO(T)HY (S)EAN S(E)AN (C)RAIG C(R)AIG G(E)ORG(E) (T)IMO(T)HY CR(A)IG (G)EOR(G)E NIV(E)N CO(N)(N)ERRY (T)IMO(T)HY

 (The actors - in chronological order - are: David Niven, Sean Connery, George Lazenby, Roger Moore, Timothy Dalton, Pierce Brosnan, and Daniel Craig.)

 The omitted letters, read in order spell A BRIT SECRET AGENT (spacing mine).

All of which points towards one particular man!

 The fictional British secret agent, James Bond.


Ah shoot you got the correct answer

You indexed the answer correctly too I will remove mine

Indeed it's him, good job!

@Stiv Congratulations on becoming the highest reputation person on Puzzling!

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Thanks very much :) As long as my questions can entertain and my answers can be useful, I'm happy :D

The name's Stiv, 001 Stiv. Congratulations on achieving this at a fast pace, and for all the great questions and answers - especially the long unsolved ones!

Thanks @Tom - and I do love solving the longstanding ones. The moment of realisation that you're finally seeing something you (or anyone else) hadn't before is a big buzz :)
